# How to deal with package date from wireshark

Tags: wireshark, bigdata

Here's the thing.I come with a problem when I process the Internet packet Information in Wireshark.I need a tools can help me handle a large number of packets and take the packet information (I mean the data inside the packet which be show as hexadecimal and cut out the specific part) out from the Wireshark and can be order by specific order. Well,If it can generate a form I will very appreciate that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> I come with a problem when I process the Internet package Information in Wireshark

(In English, the term that's usually used is "packet", not "package"; I assume you're referring to network packets here.)

Are you processing them using Wireshark, or some other program?

> I need a tools can help me handle a large number of packages and take the package information (I mean the data inside the package which be show as hexadecimal and cut out the specific part) out from the Wireshark and can be order by specific order.

Capture files written by Wireshark are either in pcap or pcap-ng format; libpcap/WinPcap can read pcap files, and libpcap 1.1.0 and later can read many pcap-ng files.  A packet record in those files has a time stamp giving the date and time the packet was received (in UTC, represented as time since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC), the length of the packet as it appeared on the network, the amount of packet data that was saved (capture programs can be told to save no more than *N* bytes of packet data, with the user specifying the value of *N*), and the raw packet data in binary form.

You could use libpcap/WinPcap to read those files (although older versions of libpcap, and current versions of WinPcap, can't read pcap-ng files).  The packets in a file aren't guaranteed to be sorted by the time stamp value, so you'd have to sort them yourself.

I don't know what you mean by "cut out the specific part"; if you want to extract particular parts of the packet's data, you'll either have to write your own code to understand that or find some tool that will help you do that - the TShark `-T fields` option might work here, as might [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

Comment: I'm sorry about my English level. Yes.I'm processing the packet in wireshark.I need to extract the special part of each packet I capture and generate a form.Can Scapy help me finish it?

Comment: That depends on what "the special part" is.  What particular part of which particular types of packets are you trying to extract?